# ios - how do I make a screen with content scrollable and reuse styles?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am building a screen that will have a tutorial article, and is obviously going to be longer than just one screen.  Here is a screen shot of what I am building:

[image]

This is a first page like this I ever built, so I am not sure how to enable scrolling. So far I just typed the text into the labels by hand, and had to remember the shade of blue that I used for the heading, but this feels like an incredibly wrong approach in this case.

How do I make the page scroll for me so I can add more labels, and how do I create a universal style for the labels and the headings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your article as HTML with CSS for formatting and then make the view that contains it a `UIWebView`.

Example:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Layout" ofType:@"html"];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Comment: would I just create it as an actual html page with all the <head> and <body> and <div> tags? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the web view is a mini browser with CSS and JavaScript support.  It sometimes takes a bit of fiddling with Xcode to make sure all the HTML-related files end up in the right build phase (copy rather than compile) but it works fine.  (I use it for reference-type 'Help' in apps.)

Comment: ah I see, so I wouldn't really put any elements on the page in the storyboard, but instead, when the screen loads, reference that html layout with the css? One thing is - if I want to put buttons into the middle of that page, how would I do that? Would I still be able to connect those buttons to go to other screens?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You can make HTML controls and, on some systems, use JavaScript to communicate with the host environment...but I've heard that's not available for iOS.  The other possibility is to create a `UIWebViewDelegate` and implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`.  If your button invokes a URL, I would expect you could intercept it in that method and handle it as necessary...but no guarantees; I haven't actually done it.

Comment: After thinking about, I realized I was assuming your second question meant 'screens' related to other view controllers.  On the other hand, if what you mean by "go to other screens" is simply other HTML pages, that would work fine.